# How to handle spaces in a jdbc outbound query parameter?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-integration

I don't know if this is integration related, but in my context I try to reference a payload value by a key that contains spaces:

```xml
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter 
    query="INSERT INTO table (serial, dealer_code) VALUES (:payload[SERIES], :payload[DEALER CODE])"
    data-source="dbDataSource">

</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

While the `:payload[SERIES]` parameter works, as long as I add the second one neither of:

- `:payload[DEALER CODE]`
- `:payload['DEALER CODE']`
- `:payload[&quot;DEALER CODE&quot;]`

Work, moreover the last two break with a:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'payload[': Invalid property 'payload[' of bean class [org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage]: Bean property 'payload[' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

While elsewhere, in another enpoint configuration I do use quotes:

```xml
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="/api/requests"
    ...
    status-code-expression="T(org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder).requestAttributes.request.method.equals('POST') ? 201 : 200">

</int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I've worked around this adding an `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` (as explained in [Inbound Channel Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter)):

```xml
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter 
    query="INSERT INTO table (serial, dealer_code) VALUES (:serial, :dealerCode)"
    sql-parameter-source-factory="spelSource"
    data-source="dbDataSource">

</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="spelSource"
  class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <entry key="serial" value="payload['SERIES']"/>
            <entry key="dealerCode" value="payload['DEALER CODE']"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

But since payload fields are just read, this seems too much.

Am I using the wrong syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` for the `sql-parameter-source-factory` attribute of the `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter >`. And yes, indeed, that expression must be like this: `:payload['DEALER CODE']`.

Comment: I already had a source factory configured but forgot to show it (updated my post): is this what you're suggesting? Because `:payload[SERIES]` works without the source factory.

Comment: No, you are good there. The difference that by default it uses `BeanPropertySqlParameterSourceFactory` ,which is not based on the SpEL. And the problem that parameter parses ends up on the whitespace. Therefore it extract a param name as `payload['DEALER` which is wrong for you. Therefore it would be better to configure extra bean for remapping your target key to the readable parameter name ,like you in your latest config.